# Is there a word or expression to describe that "it satisfies only the specific needs and nothing else"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, synonyms

We're creating a new process to give users access to the files and commands they need in a more black-boxed concept so that we can give them only access to what they need, and nothing else (making it more precise on a user level).

So, to create a kind of slogan I wanted to know if there is a word or expression to describe that "it satisfies only the specific needs and nothing else"?

Comment: You need to be careful about "sloganising" this concept. What you're describing is normally seen as ***restricted/limited access*** - where many users can only access some subset of available data, procedures, etc. But if you ask them whether they actually *want* that, they'll invariably say they'd rather have ***full access*** even if this means they'll end up looking at "advanced" configuration screens where they're no idea what they might want to change, or why. If they were the same price, would you rather have *Windows Home Basic*, or *Windows Professional?*

Comment: The target audience is a security expert who doesn't want anyone to have access. And we want to add a little flexibility to it without compromising the safety of our systems.

Comment: In that case, just call it "restricted access" and your security expert will be happy. There are probably more "domain-specific" usages in this general area, but they're not very relevant to "learning English" in the broader context.

Comment: If I use only "restricted access" the will say that is nothing new. ;-)

Comment: Well, they're security experts, not literary critics looking to award you top marks for interesting and creative use of language. I'd say that *almost by definition*, people in that line of work would like everything described using well-established clear-cut terminology (they might even endorse "Nothing new!" as a slogan! :)

Comment: I love your arguments @FumbleFingers ! ;-)

Comment: Nice of you to say so, thanks. I know it might look like I'm just being a smart-ass, but I am genuinely trying to steer you in the right direction here. The thing is in your *specific* context you're not interested in promoting the hypothetical *user* benefit of a ***simpler*** user interface. In reality it's probably actually a much *more* complex system. Customised user access provision can get quite complicated, as you've probably discovered (so you feel proud of what you've done because it was hard work, even though the *actual* users might never really notice or care).

Comment: Yes, I understand but for our specific case I need to promote use benefits as well. :-)

Comment: Good luck with that! You can fool all of the people some of the time, and some of the people all of the time. But it's not easy to write a glowing account of your latest software update when your target audience includes a *security expert who doesn't want anyone to have access*, and a bunch of users who're likely to *say* they want access to everything, even though they'd only screw things up if you gave it to them.

Comment: When non of the extremes want to give up you give them a proposal in the middle and if you're a deal maker they'll  accept it. Now let's hope I'm a deal maker. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to emphasize that each person has different access, or that access in general is restricted?

For the first, you may try [tailored](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tailored)

specially made for a particular purpose or situation.

(British English speakers might use 'bespoke' instead)

Comment: James Bond said his tuxedo was "tailored" in *Casino Royale*, but this might have been for the benefit of American audiences.  Anyway another phrase is "custom-fit".

Comment: I'm trying to emphasize that every user needs different access but a many cases they get a general out-of-the-box type that may be too much (security risks can be involved).

Comment: For years I thought "bespoke" was a kind of fabric, because in British novels I'd read about someone wearing a "bespoke suit", and I never heard the word anywhere else...